# ClientAuthError: state_mismatch: State mismatch error. Please check your network. Continued requests may cause cache overflow

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, msal.js, msal-react, msal

I use `msal-browser v2.37.1` with `Nuxt3` /`Vue3` and it works totally fine in most cases.
It works fine when the window.location url looks like this:

`https://test.com` or `https://test.com/user/2?page=profile`

but shows for some reason, when I add an additional query param, it starts to fail, for e.g.

`https://test.com/user/2?page=profile&section=identification` and gives these error:

*ClientAuthError: state_mismatch: State mismatch error. Please check your network. Continued requests may cause cache overflow.*
*at ClientAuthError2.AuthError2 [as constructor]*

So, just by adding an extra param, it starts complaining.

I tried investigating the msal source code but couldn't find the snippet where this error occurs.
I tried adding `state` in the msal config when initiating a request, but same result.

EDIT: Upon more investivation, found that the serverResponseHash and cachedState do not match.

[MSAL Source Code - Showing the exact place where it throws the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQo9R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the cache location to 'localStorage'.
This change is needed in the msal config before creating an instance of PublicClientApplication.

```
auth: {
  ...
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
  storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
},
```